# Not able to get a semicolon separated string after looping through a list in c#

Tags: c#, string, list

I am new to C# and .Net core. I wish to get a string from  a setter _modelDetails, but I am facing an issue. Below is its detailed description. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have a json as below:

```
 "VehicleDetails": [
    {
      "vehicleId": "vehicleId",     
      "vehicleName": "vehicleName",
      "version": "Version",
      "modelDetails": [
        {
          "year": "1900",
          "color": "blue",
          "transaction": [
            {
              "transactionName": "transactionName1"
            },
            {
              "transactionName": "transactionName2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "year": "2000",
          "color": "green",
          "transaction": [
            {
              "transactionName": "transactionName3"
            },
            {
              "transactionName": "transactionName4"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

For the json, below are part of the models:

```
public class VehicleDetails : IValidatableObject {
    public  List<string> _modelDetails
       public List<MobileDetails> modelDetails
        {
            get => _modelDetails;
            set
            {
                _modelDetails = value;                   
                string transactionName = "";
                _modelDetails?.ForEach(model =>
                {            
                    foreach (var transaction in model.Transaction)
                    {
                        transactionName = transaction.DisplayName;                  
                        break;
                    }               
                    _modelDetails = model.TagId + ";" + model.DisplayName + ";" + transactionName;
                    Console.WriteLine(_modelDetails);
                    
                });
            }
        }
    }   
      
   
 public class ModelDetails :IValidatableObject
    {  
        private List<Transaction> _transactions;    
        public List<Transaction> Transaction { 
      

      
        get => _transactions;
        set
        {
            _transactions = value;           
        }
        
    } 

    public List<IValidatableObject> GetChildObjects()
    {
        var childObjects = new List<IValidatableObject>() ;
        if(Transaction?.Count > 0) childObjects.AddRange(Transaction);
        return childObjects.Count > 0 ? childObjects : null;
    }
}

public class Transaction: IValidatableObject
{     
    public string TransactionName { get; set; }   
    public List<IValidatableObject> GetChildObjects()
    {
        return null;
    }    
}
```

I need the _modelDetails to return a semicolon separated strings as below:

```
1900;blue;transactionName1
1900;blue;transactionName2
2000;green;transactionName3
2000;green;transactionName4
```

But right now its just returning these two strings:

```
1900;blue;transactionName1 and 
2000;green;transactionName3
```

I seems simple logically but I am not getting where I am going wrong. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

well you say only process the first transaction

```
               foreach (var transaction in model.Transaction)
                {
                    transactionName = transaction.DisplayName;                  
                    break; <<<<=======
                }
```

probably you want

```
                foreach (var transaction in model.Transaction)
                {
                    transactionName = transaction.DisplayName;                  
                    _modelDetails = model.TagId + ";" + model.DisplayName + ";" + transactionName;
                    Console.WriteLine(_modelDetails);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<VehicleDetail> vehicleDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json).VehicleDetails;
    
List<string> modelDetails = vehicleDetails[0].ModelDetails;
```

output

```
1900;blue;transactionName1
1900;blue;transactionName2
2000;green;transactionName3
2000;green;transactionName4
```

And I had to fix your classes to deserialize json

```
public class Root
{
    public List<VehicleDetail> VehicleDetails { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleDetail : IValidatableObject
{
    public string vehicleId { get; set; }
    public string vehicleName { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("modelDetails")]
    private List<ModelDetail> _modelDetailsList;
    private List<string> modelDetails=new List<string>();

  public List<string> ModelDetails
   {
     get
    {
      if (modelDetails.Count == 0)
      {
        foreach (var model in _modelDetailsList)
         foreach (var transaction in model.Transaction)
          modelDetails.Add(model.year + ";" + model.color + ";" + transaction.TransactionName + "\n");
      }
    return modelDetails;
  }
 }
}

public class ModelDetail : IValidatableObject
{
    public string year { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    private List<Transaction> _transaction;
    public List<Transaction> Transaction
    {

       get => _transaction;
        set
        {
            _transaction = value;
        }
    }

    public List<IValidatableObject> GetChildObjects()
    {
        var childObjects = new List<IValidatableObject>();
        if (Transaction?.Count > 0) childObjects.AddRange(Transaction);
        return childObjects.Count > 0 ? childObjects : null;
    }
}

public class Transaction : IValidatableObject
{
    public string TransactionName { get; set; }
    public List<IValidatableObject> GetChildObjects()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```